# Why isn't expr performing arithmetic on real number using in a shell script?

Tags: command-line, scripts

```
a=10.5
b=11.8
c=`expr $a + $b | bc`
echo $c
```

After execution, it's displaying an error message like `non-integer argument`. Why is this not performing arithmetic using `expr`?

Comment: To make a code block look nice, select the lines that should be in it and press the `{}` button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation of errors

The error is the same as if you input:

```
$ expr 10.5 + 11.8
expr: non-integer argument
```

Expr is complaining that you gave it non-integers. This is because `expr` program was not designed for non-integer calculations:

[Expr invocation](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/expr-invocation.html):

> Operands are either integers or strings.

- `expr` was generated as standard error, your terminal just displays it
- But when you use pipe `|`, pipe only transfers  standard out, not standard error
- Because `bc` did not receive anything to work with, it didn't give you any output at all, as you can see when you try sending nothing (except new-line) to `bc`:

  ```
  $ echo | bc
  ```

The result is `bc` says nothing. So what you see on your screen with your original command, was still just `expr`'s complaint via standard error.

### Recommendation

For decimal calculations, you can use just `bc` and some means to get input to `bc`, such as with here-strings:

```
$ bc <<< '10.5 + 11.8'
22.3
```

Or, to use variables:

```
$ a=10.5
$ b=11.8
$ c=$(bc <<< "$a + $b")
$ echo $c
22.3
```

- The `$(` and `)` is a command substitution
- `<<< string` is a here-string syntax, sends the string contents to stdin, which bc receives

Answer (score 1):

`info coreutils 'expr invocation'` says:

```
16.4 `expr': Evaluate expressions
=================================

`expr' evaluates an expression and writes the result on standard
output.  Each token of the expression must be a separate argument.

   Operands are either integers or strings.  Integers consist of one or
more decimal digits, with an optional leading `-'.  `expr' converts
anything appearing in an operand position to an integer or a string
depending on the operation being applied to it.
```

However, you can use `bc`:

```
$ a=10.5 b=11.8 c=$(echo "scale=1;$a + $b" | bc -q );echo $c
22.3
```

Comment: why  c=` expr $a  + $b | bc ` not working ?

Comment: Because it's `expr 10.5 + 11.8` see above